# (Simple) Push Notification using REST with Silverlight 4?

Tags: rest, silverlight-4.0, push-notification, server-push

What is the best way to implement a push notification service using RESTful WCF services with Silverlight 4 clients?

We are currently using a polling technique to call the REST service for updates. I'd prefer to have the server push, or broadcast, the notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of closure, I thought I'd share what we ended up doing.

We did create a push notification server running as a Windows Service using standard Sockets communication.  We maintain a list of connected clients and push notifications out as needed.

It's not RESTful, but since the client isn't making requests, it didn't make much sense to implement in a RESTful manner.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Pusher (who I work for) and our Silverlight library. See: http://pusher.com/docs/client_libraries#dotnet

Update:
Since you state you can't use a hosted service and you don't want to use WebSockets (although I'd still suggest WebSockets are the best option) you can get HTTP Streaming to work reliably. I'd recommend you use a dedicated realtime server for your push notifications if you need to scale your application. You can find a bunch of realtime self-hosted solutions list here:
http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-technologies-guide

Twitter use Jetty for their HTTP Streaming API (Firehose etc.) so it will provide a scalable and reliable solution.

Happy to provide more information if you can elaborate further on your question.

Comment: A hosted service is not an option. These are internal applications running in VERY secure, self-contained environments (i.e. no outside access) and the number of installations is in the thousands.

Comment: Pusher also relies on WebSockets which are unreliable to say the least in SL4 not to mention that they require the SL app to be run in-browser which, of course, we are not. ;-)

Comment: If you control the runtime environment and network then you can most definitely make WebSockets work reliably. I'd be surprised if WebSockets need to run in-browser. The implementation uses the underlying SL networking stack. But it may be the case.